# Using Wronskian to explain behavior.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, wronskian

I have the following problem:

In Section $4.2$ it was shown that if $\mathbf x_1$ and $\mathbf x_2$ are solutions of

$$ \mathbf x' =
\begin{pmatrix}
p_{11}(t) & p_{12}(t) \\
p_{21}(t) & p_{22}(t) \\
\end{pmatrix}\mathbf x
$$

on an interval *I*, then the Wronskian *W* of $\mathbf{x_1}$ and $\mathbf{x_2}$ satisfies the differential equation $W' = (p_{11}+p_{22})W$. A generalization of that proof shows that if $\mathbf{x_1,\cdots,x_n}$ are solutions of $$\mathbf{x'=Ax,\ \ \ \ \ x}(0) = \mathbf{x}_0$$
on I, then the Wronskian of $\mathbf{x_1,\cdots,x_n}$, denoted by *W*, satisfies the differential equation

$$W' = (p_{11} +p_{22}+ \cdots + p_{nn})W = tr(\mathbf{P}(t))W~.\tag{i}$$

**(a)** Explain why Eq. (i) also implies that *W* is either identically zero or else never vanishes on *I* in accordance with Theorem 6.2.5 (shown below).

**(b)** If $y_1,\cdots,y_n$ are solutions of

$$\frac{d^ny}{dt^n}+p_1(t)\frac{d^{n-1}y}{dt^{n-1}}+ \cdots +p_{n-1}(t)\frac{dy}{dt}+p_n(t)y =0,$$

find a counterpart to Eq. (i) satisfied by $W = W[y_1,\cdots,y_n](t)$.

**Theorem $6.2.5$ :**

Let $x_1,\cdots,x_n$ be solutions of $\mathbf{x' = p(t)x}$ on an interval $I = (\alpha , \beta)$ in which **P**(t) is continuous.

(i) If $\mathbf{x}_1,\cdots,\mathbf{x}_n$ are linearly independent on *I*, then $W[\mathbf{x}_1,\cdots,\mathbf{x}_n](t) \ne0$ at every point in *I*,

(ii) If $\mathbf{x}_1,...,\mathbf{x}_n$ are linearly dependent on *I*, then $W[\mathbf{x}_1,...,\mathbf{x}_n](t) =0$ at every point in *I*.

$$$$
$$$$

For (a), I'm having trouble trying to figure out where to start. I know what a Wronskian is, but I don't know how I would prove that W is either zero or never vanishes using (i)

For (b), I'm not sure what the problem is asking.

Answer (score 0):

(a) *Hint*: What is the solution to $y' = ky$?  This solution has an arbitrary constant: for which values of this constant does the solution vanish?

(b) Recall that an $n^\text{th}$ order linear differential equation can be turned into a system of $n$ first order differential equations by letting $x_1 = y, x_2 = y', \ldots, x_n = y^{(n-1)}$.  What is the resulting system of differential equations?  If you write this system in matrix form as $\mathbf{x'} = \mathbf{Ax}$, what is the trace of $\mathbf{A}$?